# Circle containing 9 buttons and rotate on button press, iOS?

Tags: ios, button, graphics, rotation

I am working on a project where I need to show 9 buttons on a circle and press of any button circle should rotate to the indicator which shows the button pressed. How to achieve this in iOS?

Your suggestions will be appreciated. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets Try this

```
UIButton *button;

button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:button];

CABasicAnimation *halfTurn;
halfTurn = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
halfTurn.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
halfTurn.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
halfTurn.duration = 0.5;
halfTurn.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[[button layer] addAnimation:halfTurn forKey:@"180"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use external library then this might be the better option. I have done  using carousel library . Please refer following link https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel .This is easy and better to implement. You can add the button view as the item in the carousel view.

Comment: How can I rotate buttons in circular fashion by using this?

Comment: have you used that ? You have to use iCarouselTypeWheel for this . You dont have to do anything for the rotation . You just need to give the view components .You have to use [carousel scrollToItemAtIndex: animated:

Answer (score 0):

You want to rotate whole circle or only particular button is not clear from your question. If you want to rotate whole circle just use `CALayer`animation Class to achieve this.Just set the buttons frame and animate it with animation of rotation

Answer (score 0):

You can use next classes

[KYCircleMenu](https://github.com/Kjuly/KYCircleMenu)

[ALRadial](https://github.com/alattis/ALRadial)